# Explaining how localization effects my MVC application, format changing when deploying to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, localization

My ASP.NET MVC has a form, on my laptop I can put in a date with the format dd/mm/yyyy so:

26/09/2014

When I deploy to my server, I get a validation error when I enter the exact same above address.

I have to enter:

09/26/2014

Then it works fine.

I want to preserve the dd/mm/yyyy on my production server also, what should I change to make this work?

Comment: I assume because you are entering the date in American format ('mm/dd/yyyy'). There is no 26th month, so the validation fails. So what's the problem? Is your production server in a different culture setting?

Comment: @gunr2171 I'm not sure what settings my production server has, but what should I change localization wise in my application so it is always consistant dd/mm/yyyy.

Comment: If you don't force any sort of culture, the program will use the current format (whatever the computer is set to). Even if you pull a DateTime from a database, it will still be in the right format. I would need to see more of your code to say anymore.

Comment: You need to convert the local date into UTC/ISO format before posting to server.